# Symfony 3.4 entity property with array of items from another entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I have two entities:

ENTITY 1 - BRAND:

```
<?php
namespace ...;
//Here the use definitions

class Brand
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    //More properties, getters and setters
}
?>
```

ENTITY 2 - PRODUCT:

```
<?php
namespace ...;
//Here the use definitions

class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $brand;

    //More properties, getters and setters
}
?>
```

I know that I can get the products of a brand consulting `PRODUCT` directly, thanks to ORM. But is there a way to get all the products consulting over `BRAND` entity?

I mean, is there a way that adding a property into `BRAND` entity, something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Producto")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="brand_id")
 * })
 */
private $listOfProducts;
```

Can I get a list of products?

Comment: Yes this is pretty much what you're trying to do I think? 

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. On your Brand entity, add OneToMany column like this :

```
<?php
namespace ...;
//Here the use definitions

class Brand
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="brand")
     */
    private $products;

    //More properties, getters and setters
}
?>
```

Comment: It was what I want,Works perfect.